# Creating a perfectly balanced binary tree in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have been writing some code to try make a perfectly balanced tree from an array though i run into issues when I tree and make the list bigger than 3 elements i get the error "Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?)". I was if this is was because my quite inefficient implementation or of some other mistake I have made? Thanks for any help it will be greatly appreciate, code below.

ps - I also realise I should have used fold_left for the helper functions but I did not them understand it till after doing this

```
 type 'a binary_tree =
      | Empty
      | Node of 'a * 'a binary_tree * 'a binary_tree;;


 let length lst = 
     let rec aux acc = function
          | [] -> acc
          | x::xs -> aux (acc+1) xs
     in
     aux 0 lst;;

 let mid lst = 
     let rec aux count = function
         | [] -> None
         | x::xs -> if (count=0) then Some x else aux (count-1) xs
     in
     aux ((length lst)/2) lst;;

  let left lst = 
      let rec aux count acc = function
           | [] -> []
           | x::xs -> if (count=0) then acc else aux (count-1) (acc@[x]) xs
       in
       aux ((length lst)/2) [] lst;;


  let right lst = 
      let rec aux count = function
          | [] -> []
          | x::y::xs -> if (count=0) then xs else aux (count-1) (y::xs)
      in
      aux (((length lst)/2)-1) lst;;

  let rec createTree lst = match lst with
      | [x] -> Node((Some x),Empty,Empty)
      | xs -> Node((mid xs), (createTree(left xs)), (createTree(right xs)));;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notwithstanding the implementation efficiency, the recursive loop stems
from the missing empty case `[]`: since `left [] = []` and `right [] = []`, `createTree []` is extended to `Node(mid [], createTree [], createTree [])` which leads to the stack overflow.

On the efficiency side, note that your worse function is `left` which is quadratic rather than linear in its input size due to the list concatenation `acc @ [x]` which is computed for each elements. For this case, performance will be much better by reversing the list at the end of `left`.

Another point, it could make sense to group together `left`, `mid`, `right` in a `partition` function to avoid some repetitions.

Comment: Thanks for you help well explained aswell

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List.length` directly instead of defining it yourself ;)

Also, if you dont particularily need to preserve the order of your elements, you can compute your `mid`, `left` and `right` values by taking the first element of a list, and splitting the rest as in the following :

```
let split l = 
  let rec loop left right flag rest =
    match rest with
    | [] -> left,right
    | h::t -> 
       if flag then loop (h::left) right (not flag) t
       else loop left (h::right) (not flag) t
  in loop [] [] true l
```

By switching `flag` to `not flag` at every step, you send one in every two element into the left list, and the other into the right one.
Your `createTree` function thus becomes :

```
let rec createTree lst = 
  match lst with
  | [] -> Empty
  | h::t -> 
    let left,right = split t in  
    Node(h, (createTree left), (createTree right))
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your help as well but my idea was to use a sorted array that would then produce a balanced binary search tree rather than just a binary tree, but using the flags with a single list could still help :)